# How can I add items to Context.data without loosing it once I exit the inner_function

Tags: python, python-2.7, closures

I am having some trouble with Python Closures, hoping someone here could help. Below is my code.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


class Context(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.data = []


context = Context(1, 2)


def test(text):

    def inner_function():
        for i in range(0, 10):
            text.data.append(i)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(text.data.__len__())

    thread = Process(target=inner_function)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

test(context)
time.sleep(12)
print("Final {0}".format(context.data.__len__()))
```

The output that I am seeing is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Final 0
```

I want Final to have a value of 10. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: there is a problem in your code - you define `context` but everywhere else you seem to call it `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not about closures but about [sharing data between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) as in `thread` everything works as expected but you do not pass back your data to the main process.

You could return `context` explicity and maybe using [Pool.apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply) or apply_async is the right thing for this.

Comment: Thanks that insight helped.